# html table sort function is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html

Html table sorting is not working properly, i have a demo on below link. please focus the columns names - row count and sl.no.

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/46xndqfp/)

HTML:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr height=50>
<th>SL.NO</th>
<th>Database Name</th>
<th>Table Name</th>
<th>Table Size in MB</th>
<th>Table Size in GB</th>
<th>Unused space in MB</th>
<th>Engine Type</th>
<th>Row Count</th>
<th>Time</th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>1</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>Attractions</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.42</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.00041015625</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>726</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>AttractionsType</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.02</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>1.953125e-05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>11</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>3</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>AttractionsType_lang</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.02</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>1.953125e-05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>43</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>4</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>Attractions_lang</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>1.52</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.001484375</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>4</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2359</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>5</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>Category</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.02</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>1.953125e-05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>4</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>6</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>Category_lang</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.02</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>1.953125e-05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>16</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>7</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>City</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.3</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.00029296875</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>1596</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>8</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>CityHotelCategoryMaping</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.06</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>5.859375e-05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>5</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>9</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>City_lang</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.42</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.00041015625</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>374</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>10</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>Cloudinaryphoto</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.22</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.00021484375</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>397</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>11</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>Country</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>MyISAM</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>4</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>12</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>Country_lang</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.02</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>1.953125e-05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>12</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>13</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>Currency</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.02</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>1.953125e-05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>14</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>Currency_lang</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.02</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>1.953125e-05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>8</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>15</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HomeBlockPackages</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.02</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>1.953125e-05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>12</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>16</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HomeBlocks</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.02</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>1.953125e-05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>3</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>17</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HomeBlocks_lang</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.02</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>1.953125e-05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>9</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>18</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HomeFront</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.02</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>1.953125e-05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>5</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>19</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HomeFrontType</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.02</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>1.953125e-05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>6</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>20</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HomeFront_lang</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.02</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>1.953125e-05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>15</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>21</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HomePageFooterLinks</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.02</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>1.953125e-05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>22</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HomePagepkgLinks</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.02</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>1.953125e-05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>8</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>23</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HomePagePkgLinksPackages</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.02</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>1.953125e-05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>48</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>24</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HomePagepkgLinks_lang</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.02</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>1.953125e-05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>25</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>25</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>Hotel</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.19</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.000185546875</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>320</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>26</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>Hotel_lang</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>1.52</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.001484375</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>4</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>715</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>27</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>Image</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.06</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>5.859375e-05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>28</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>Language</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.02</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>1.953125e-05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>7</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>29</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>Newsletter</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.02</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>1.953125e-05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>81</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>30</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>Package</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.2</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.0001953125</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>50</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>31</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>PackageAttractions</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.03</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2.9296875e-05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>32</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>PackageCity</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.31</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.000302734375</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>394</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>33</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>PackageCity_lang</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.47</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.000458984375</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>602</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>34</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>PackageHotel</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.09</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>8.7890625e-05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>507</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>35</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>PackageMapDisplay</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.02</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>1.953125e-05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>7</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>36</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>PackagePricing</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>4.8828125e-05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>37</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>PackageRouting</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>4.8828125e-05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>323</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>38</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>PackageTheme</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.02</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>1.953125e-05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>125</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>39</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>Package_lang</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>1.52</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.001484375</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>4</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>196</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>40</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>Pricing</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.03</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2.9296875e-05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>41</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>Pricingamount</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>4.8828125e-05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>601</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>42</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>Pricingdaterange</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.02</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>1.953125e-05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>122</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>43</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>Query</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.16</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.00015625</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>207</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>44</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>Seo</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>4.8828125e-05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>59</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>45</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>State</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>MyISAM</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>16</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>46</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>State_lang</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.02</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>1.953125e-05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>48</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>47</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>StaticContent</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.02</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>1.953125e-05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>48</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>Theme</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.02</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>1.953125e-05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>12</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>49</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>Theme_lang</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.02</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>1.953125e-05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>36</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr><tr height=30><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>50</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>HolidayIndia</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>User</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0.02</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>1.953125e-05</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>0</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>InnoDB</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>17</td><td ALIGN='CENTER' VALIGN='MIDDLE'>2014-10-26 23:11:15</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Javascript:

```
function sortTable(table, col, reverse) {
    var tb = table.tBodies[0], // use `<tbody>` to ignore `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` rows
        tr = Array.prototype.slice.call(tb.rows, 0), // put rows into array
        i;
    reverse = -((+reverse) || -1);
    tr = tr.sort(function (a, b) { // sort rows
        return reverse // `-1 *` if want opposite order
            * (a.cells[col].textContent.trim() // using `.textContent.trim()` for test
                .localeCompare(b.cells[col].textContent.trim())
               );
    });
    for(i = 0; i < tr.length; ++i) tb.appendChild(tr[i]); // append each row in order
}

function makeSortable(table) {
    var th = table.tHead, i;
    th && (th = th.rows[0]) && (th = th.cells);
    if (th) i = th.length;
    else return; // if no `<thead>` then do nothing
    while (--i >= 0) (function (i) {
        var dir = 1;
        th[i].addEventListener('click', function () {sortTable(table, i, (dir = 1 - dir))});
    }(i));
}

function makeAllSortable(parent) {
    parent = parent || document.body;
    var t = parent.getElementsByTagName('table'), i = t.length;
    while (--i >= 0) makeSortable(t[i]);
}

window.onload = function () {makeAllSortable();};
```

CSS:

```
table {width: 100%;font: 12px arial;}
th, td {min-width: 40px;text-align: center;}
th {font-weight: bold;cursor:pointer;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your values are sorted as text. You should convert numeric values to int. Use `parseFloat` to convert string values to numeric and sort them.

```
tr = tr.sort(function (a, b) { // sort rows
    str_a = a.cells[col].textContent.trim()
    str_b = b.cells[col].textContent.trim()
    val_a = parseFloat(str_a)
    val_b = parseFloat(str_b)

    if(!isNaN(val_a) && !isNaN(val_b)){
        var compar;
        if(val_a < val_b){
            compar = -1;
        }else if(val_a > val_b){
            compar = 1;
        }else{
            compar = 0;
        }
        return reverse*compar;
    }
    ...
  ...
...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/46xndqfp/1/

Comment: thank you very much, it's working fine.. and one more thing is how to add up and down arrow for representing the sorting clicks

Comment: This demo is too complicated. In a nutshell: if you compare strings, "5" will be greater than "12" because "5" > "1". If you want to sort numeric items properly, you should convert them to numbers before comparing.

Comment: thank you for your commands, how to add up and down arrows on header

Comment: Read more about css, classes and jquery. Or see more demos.